# Posting a message in Symphony from Python

Tags: python, api, post, get, request

I'm trying to send a message from Symphony using Python.

https://developers.symphony.com/restapi/reference#create-message-v4

I found this page but I don't really know how to use it ( There's a cURL and a post url .. ) and I don't understand how I can use requests in this context ( still a beginner in API ).

Can someone help me to figure out how I can use this page to send a message from Python.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass some required things in headers and use multipart/from-data content-type.
If you know about the postman then first with that and pass required headers.

```
files ={"message":"<messageML>Hello world!</messageML>"}
headers={
"sessionToken": "SESSION_TOKEN",
"keyManagerToken": "KEY_MANAGER_TOKEN"
}
requests.post("https://YOUR-AGENT-URL.symphony.com/agent/v4/stream/:sid/message/create", files=files,headers=headers)
```

Comment: in case it isn't obvious, requests is just the python module requests. so import requests

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/finos/symphony-bdk-python/blob/main/examples has alot of examples on how to use symphony sdk. From python you don't want to use the api. This is the simple code to send a message from a bot. If you do not have a bot set up yet, follow  https://docs.developers.symphony.com/building-bots-on-symphony/configuration/configure-your-bot-for-bdk-2.0-for-python NOTE you will need an admin user to follow these steps.

```
from symphony.bdk.core.config.loader import BdkConfigLoader
from symphony.bdk.core.symphony_bdk import SymphonyBdk

config = BdkConfigLoader.load_from_file("config.yaml")

async with SymphonyBdk(config) as bdk:
    streams = bdk.streams()
    messages = bdk.messages()
    user_id = 123  # this can be found by clicking on a profile and copy profile link eg symphony://?userId=31123123123
    stream = await streams.create_im_or_mim([user_id])
    await messages.send_message(stream.id, f"<messageML>Message you want to send</messageML>")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.